# IFRAME load clears browser undo stack

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, textarea

I am seeing this strange behavior on IE 9, Chrome 19 on OS X Lion, and Safari 5.1.5 on OS Lion (but not FF 12 OS X Lion).

http://jsfiddle.net/N6t8P/6/

Whenever I load an iframe on the page, the undo stack gets reset. Try the JSFiddle example by typing some things in the textarea, pressing the button to load the iframe, then try undo in the textarea. Undo doesn't work after an iframe load.

Is there any way I can get around this besides implementing my own undo stack?